# Unable to stop debugging on Visual Studio without needing to reboot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, kill-process

I am working on an application where multiple threads can access the same serial port.

I get `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll` all while the program is still executing without breaking due to having a try/catch pair.

Problem comes when I try to break this instance with pressing the red square `STOP` button, Visual Studio then freezes (except the Diagnostic Tools that seems to work partially). I can not kill it with task manager, with `taskkill` I can kill Visual Studio instances but not the debug of my application as that instance does not exist despite showing up with `tasklist`. No success with powershell either.

Only way for me to be able to keep working on that project is to reboot the PC, which is annoying and a waste of time.

How can I avoid this problem, or ensure I can stop the debugging session successfully without having to resort to power cycling?

Comment: Report your problem to Microsoft using the tool at the top right corner of Visual Studio.